# What are the ingredients of Pheromone Trap using for controlling Fruit flies of cucumber?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, entomology, pathology, agriculture

[image]

Pheromone Traps are used for fruit fly control. But I have no idea which ingredients or chemicals are used for preparing Pheromone trap

Comment: What species do you mean - is it Bactrocera cucurbitae?

Comment: I have mention about Bactrocera cucumis